# real time collaborative python IDE, like google docs

Tags: python, ide, collaboration, real-time

I'm sorry, I'm unfamiliar with this website, so this might have already been asked (and I may have misused some of the tags).
Some friends and I are going to be coding a small program for a 24 hour coding challenge in python 3, and I was wondering if there is a program that will allow us to code together like we were on google docs, but not based in a web browser, and with text highlighting for code. I want to be able to have libraries and stuff saved locally, but the code is shared between all those participating.
preferably with a way to run the code in the program, but not required.

The last time we did this, we used pycharm and copied the code into google docs, but this was annoying because there would be multiple versions since everyone is writing at the same time on their own machine.

Thank you for your time, and sorry if this is a duplicate.

Comment: Is "not based in a web browser" a hard requirement? If not, Repl.it is friendly  https://repl.it/site/blog/multi For more options: https://alternativeto.net/software/cloud9/

Comment: Try Live Share for Visual Studio/Visual Studio Code or Teletype for Atom.